# How to get the AST of the current chrome tab from an extension?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to do some angular code analysis. In that way I need to get a list of all the declared modules in the webpage.

I could not find how to do it with the angular API ([I believe that's not possible](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/8914f8e3b1223091f54609fa40c333beedb6562a/src/loader.js#L28)) but I stumbled on [this](https://github.com/klei/ng-dependencies). Using the AST to get modules looks interesting and promising. I could use [Acorn](https://github.com/marijnh/acorn) or [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) but I was wondering if chrome had an API to get the AST of current tab. (Possible with firefox)

EDITS:

- By AST, I mean Abstract Syntax Tree. It's a data structure generated by a parser from a script to easily interpret it. All browsers use it to interpret js. More info can be found on [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)

Here is an example from wikipedia:

[image: AST Wikipedia example]

Comment: It would help if you defined "AST". I think I know what you mean, but give an explanation / short example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited in consequence

Comment: So you want to know if you can get AST from V8 in an extension, as opposed to building your own AST with a separate parser, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Chrome's V8 does not expose any internals as part of [Extension APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index), or, for that reason, [remote debugger protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/debugger).

What you see in Dev Tools is about the limit of what is exposed.

You'll need to re-parse it yourself or use a modified version of Chromium that exposes the information you need.